# Joomla form to fill and send email (the message is a composition of the fields values)

Tags: forms, email, joomla

I work with Joomla 1.7

I want to make a form with different text input.

Like : name, adress, age....

And with this form, i will compose a message and this message is send by email to someone.

I try my best but i can't make it.

I need to know if there's a module or plugin to make this.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute best component for forms is Chronoforms ([Chronoengine.com](http://www.chronoengine.com)) - It has a 'drag & drop' type editor for creating forms and can get your forms up and going in a matter of minutes.

It's best to familiarize yourself with some of the documentation so you can see what's going on - but even if you just hop in and start playing around it's easy to see what's going on.  The 'form wizard' literally walks you through the process.

I use it on every Joomla install I create!